# What is the proper way to add custom CSS/JavaScript SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to tweak the default layout in SharePoint, e.g. add...

```
.ms-number {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

... to all pages.

I know it is possible to modify a master page directly, but is it the best approach? What about themes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's SharePoint on-premises then the best way is to create a Solution with a Feature with a `<Control>` element targeting the `AdditionalPageHead` delegate control. Then you can easily turn it on/off and it works regardless of which master page you choose.

For guidance see [Adding jQuery to Every Page in SharePoint with Delegate Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

There are some ways to achive this but I always use the style library to store my customized css files and reference them from the master page in the head section. Just add these lines if procceed.

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="/Style Library/css/customized.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```

Comment: So you just change the v4.master file directly?

Comment: thank you Alvmad. Where do we go in the share point 2013 system to implement this solution you have?

Comment: This should be in the master page or page layout you desire

Answer (score 9):

easiest and best way for adding custom CSS is to add **Alternate CSS URL** from following web url in Central Administration Web App (port 3000 )

- http://portal:3000/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
  [image]

Notes:

1. first upload your css to below default and recommended location. you should already know that you can add this location to your windows **mapped network drive** and work with the files easily from your my computer like it is your local files.

   (http://portal/_catalogs/masterpage)
2. sadly even for SP1 version of SharePoint(15.0.4569.1000) this link is not visible in site setting **but** after upgrading (for tested version of 15.0.4745.1000  -  ​Aug  2015) ,this useful link is accessible under **Master page** link under **Look and Feel**

Comment: Definitely the best solution. No code, just OOB functionality, easy to configure via UI, PowerShell and code (`SPWeb.AlternateCssUrl`).

Comment: sadly, http://...:3000/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx  is not accessible/available for me.

Comment: @kttii , replace 3000 with your Central Administration Web App port.

Answer (score 2):

I usually save the Style files to a document library, and add a content editor web part to the pages I try to edit and pass the url to my stylesheet. This way I don't mess around with the Master page, and if anything goes wrong I can just delete my CEWP.

Comment: Simple and clean solution if you want to add it to couple specific pages. Not very useful when you need to add it globally.

Answer (score 2):

Register a "CustomAction" for JS.  Works great in the cloud.  Keeps branding isolated.  Easy to manage without any server side access or admin install.

- Check out John Liu's blog post at http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online
- Source code at https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage/tree/master/dist

Here's a screenshot of the configure page where you can register/de-register "CustomAction" pointers to JS files.

[image]

Comment: Cumbersome, because you need to add pages to every SiteCollection. Easier is the SP Editor Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need

If you want it across all pages in site collection,  then upload the css file to style library, add that css file reference in master page

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration  Name="/sites/sitename/Style Library/styles/sample.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```

If you want your style to apply only on a few pages. Add a script editor to the pages where you want this css file to work and add a simple `<link>` tag like

```
<link href="/sites/sitename/style library/css/filename.css
```

If you want to add css to only one page, in the same script editor use the style tag

```
<style>
/*your css codes go here*/
</style>
```

On adding the script part, 
If you want to add to masterpage use the below line in the .master file

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/style library/script/custom.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

For other pages you can use

```
<script src='/sites/sitename/script/custom.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tats detailed. How to apply CSS for all the site collections under a web application ?