# How to make minimal changes to a master page to accommodate custom CSS

Tags: master-page, css, custom, custom-masterpage

I'm looking for a way to effect the absolute minimum changes to a master page such that it can support custom CSS (and perhaps a bit of javascript code, too).

If this sounds convoluted, some context is in order: the master page (all master pages, in fact) are controlled by another part of the organization, one which is (very) risk averse, and is understandably not keen on customizing master pages for every new project.

I need to provide this group with a yes-able proposition for making just one customization to the default master page in order to do this.

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

TIA
Josh

Comment: Look in to Delegate Controls in the AdditionalPageHead context, I think you find much information about this approach, but it do require coding

Comment: Robert, from what I can tell so far, the code requirement is not too onerous. The user control still needs to live in the 14 hive, which will hopefully not be too objectionable to said risk-averse department.

Thanks, Josh

Comment: No it is a quite easy way to go, if you have permissions to activate features and deploy solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to set "Alternate CSS URL" on masterpage settings page (/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx), but this solution is very limited: no javascript, applies to all pages on site (or site collection).

Comment: Evgeny, the CSS-only limitation is a show-stopper for me 8-(

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-custom-css-javascript-sharepoint-2013-site) thread gives a good explanation o how to add custom CSS and JS without editing the masterpage and what to do when customzing the masterpage

- Solution 1: Use a delegate controle
- Solution 2: Add a css registration to your masterpage
- Solution 3 Use [custom action](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx) to deploy JS

Comment: Remko, it looks like the Delegate control is the path of least resistance, even though the requisite user control has to be in the 14 hive CONTROLTEMPLATES folder. Thanks, Josh