# How to apply font style to entire sharepoint site text?

Tags: 2013, css, design

I want to apply common font style to entire text of SharePoint 2013 site.

Is any easy way for that?

Comment: I think the answer is in [this old thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-custom-css-javascript-sharepoint-2013-site)

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS rule in the body. Create an another CSS file and refer it after all CSS file.

```
body{
  font-style: italic; //Common name goes here
}
```

Comment: its not getting applied.

Comment: try using `!important`