# How to apply a free bootstrap theme template on sharepoint web page?

Tags: theme

I want to change the theme of sharepoint web page (intranet webpage) using bootstrap ready online theme templates, how?

I want to apply a nice colors theme and reorder the content to be tidy.(changing the layout)

I am using sharepoint2013.

Can any one help me step by step, because I am new in designing web pages.

I have navigation at the top and at the left, and I prefer 3 columns layout or more.

Also, What is the best recommended? Bootstrap or third party for designing a theme for sharepoint2013?

Comment: There are lots of article available on internet like this..http://www.topsharepoint.com/shareboot-responsive-sharepoint-2013-theme

Answer (score 2):

1. One way is customizing page with SharePoint Designer, but in detail you must first [add css and javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-custom-css-javascript-sharepoint-2013-site) to page and then apply css classes to objects
2. Create your own [css](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/10/part-2-implement-custom-css-in-sharepoint-master-pages/) and use it!

Answer (score 0):

With experience, I have on using the third party theme. They work fine if you can use them as it is. You will start seeing a problem if you want to change layouts structure or want to show a page in a different format. This takes a time to fix issues.

Then we have started using a bootstrap within 3 days we have converted our site to responsive design. But it requires knowledge of CSS, HTML, JavaScript, and Bootstrap.

Here are the steps we followed.

1. Create a custom master page using SharePoint Designer.
2. Add Bootstrap CSS and JS references to the master page design files.
3. Create your custom page layouts using SharePoint designer.
4. Use Bootstrap Grid System classes for your web part zones.
5. You can design responsive web parts also.

Here is a basic article to understand [how to use Bootstrap](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016) for SharePoint sites.