# How to put a reference for a css in aspx page layout in SharePoint 2016

Tags: css, page-layout, 2016, reference

How to put a reference for a CSS in aspx page layout in SharePoint 2016

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" 
runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>
```

or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="/_layouts/1033/styles/HtmlEditorCustomStyles.css" type="text/css"
    media="all" />
```

which is the correct way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its primarily opinion based answer.

But if you want to add in `aspx` page then I would definitely go with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/HtmlEditorCustomStyles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

But if you want add in MasterPage then you must go with

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" 
runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>
```

Also if you need to add for particular site then [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/171511/30145) is the best approach for you.

Answer (score 4):

The better way of loading CSS in SharePoint world is always using `CssRegistration` tags. You can always specify the order of script load, conditional script load, also when using same master page at root level and multiple sub-site level, it provides you ease of creating URL.

See [this link](https://thomasdaly.net/2012/05/02/sharepoint-cssregistration-or-link/) for more.