# hide Name of column from document library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, column

how to hide “Name” of column from document library in SharePoint 2013

[image]

Comment: [Add custom CSS to your SharePoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-custom-css-javascript-sharepoint-2013-site) and assign `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to the element.

Comment: its a webparts document library insert in page

Comment: Where you want hide your name column from views or forms?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the name "Name", open SharePoint Designer 2013, open your site, click Lists and Libraries, click your library, click Edit List Columns and rename the "Name" column.

[image]

**Edit:**  Edit the view and uncheck "Name". You will still need a clickable link to open the documents, so leave the "Type (icon linked to document)" column in the view.

Comment: The "Edit" above is not related to the SharePoint Designer answer and is an alternate to hiding the column using views. (Not sure why they were oddly merged.)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to *Right Click* on the column header and select inspect element and get it's ID value.
- Edit your SP page and Add a Script Editor web part.
  [image]
- Click EDIT SNIPPET and paste in the below code:

  > ```
  > <style type="text/css">
  >  #yourIDGoesHere {DISPLAY: none}
  > </style>
  > ```
- Click on Insert.

Your Column header should disappear now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the browser's F12 tools you can see that you could use JavaScript or jQuery to select the  using the ID or the TITLE attributes and set a style to hide it.

```
<a title="Name, Click to sort by Name" class="ms-headerSortTitleLink" id="diidSort2LinkFilename"
```

(The answer that included this comment was deleted. I have reposted it as the person who asked the question indicated that this is the approach they are trying. (*I will try it , thanks bro – Hatim Ezzaki*) )

Answer (score 0):

While adding JavaScript would help to hide a column from a list, a much easier option could be to just open Library Section in the ribbon and click **Modify View**:

[image: Modify view]
There you can select what columns you want to be displayed in the List/Libary, simply remove the check mark from the Name:

[image: Remove check mark from name]

Here's the result:

[image: Result - No name]